# How does this callback function example work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

(I ask understanding from fellow programmers that I am re-studying nodeJS after I got out of the army. I am a beginner and question maybe too simple but please help with my understanding of the example code bellow)

```
function add(a, b, callback) {
    var result = a + b;
    callback(result);
    var count = 0;

    var history = function() {
        count += 1;
        return count +  ' : ' + a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + result;  
    };
    return history;

}

var add_history = add(20, 20, function(result) {
    console.log('addition result : ' + result);
});


console.log('execute callback function: ' + add_history());
console.log('execute callback function: ' + add_history());
```

**I expect the result to be following:**

```
addition result : 40
execute callback function: 1 : 20 + 20 = 40
addition result : 40
execute callback function: 2 : 20 + 20 = 40
```

**However, the result says:**

```
addition result : 40
execute callback function: 1 : 20 + 20 = 40
execute callback function: 2 : 20 + 20 = 40
```

Why is `console.log('addition result : ' + result);` not repeated each time `add_history()` is called from the last two statements?

Comment: because after first execution of add function you return history function, and u store it in variable add_history so when you call add_history function it will basicly run function you returned (history) and in that history function u are no longer executing callback

Comment: @MladenSkrbic is right, `add_history` becomes `history`

Comment: Right; if you declare `add_history` as a function, like `add`, you'll get the result you expect instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are returning a function from the add function.

when this block runs:

```js
var add_history = add(20, 20, function(result) {
    console.log('addition result : ' + result);
});
```

The callback gets executed, the `addition result : 40` logs to the console, and `add_history` **becomes a reference to the `history` function** you have defined in the `add` function.

Now, when you call `add_history` you are calling a reference to the `history` function which has nothing to do with the callback. But since `history` was created in the scope of `add`, you have access to the `count` variable defined in that scope.

You could call your callback by defining the `history` function inside the `add` function like this:

```js
var history = function() {
   callback(result)
   count += 1;
   return count +  ' : ' + a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + result;  
}
```

This would cause the callback to run each time you call `add_history`.